# Upgrade magento 1.9.0.1 to latest version - SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.status'

Tags: magento-1.9

I know what you are thinking, another topic with the same problem. You should disable flag catalog, delete cache and re-index all. Well that's the problem, I did all of that but I keep on getting this error. Anybody? please

```
   SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.status' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT MAX(e.min_price -(e.min_price/(1+(CASE e.tax_class_id WHEN 1 THEN       0.2100 WHEN 2 THEN       0.0600 WHEN 4 THEN       0.2100  ELSE 0 END))*CASE e.tax_class_id WHEN 1 THEN       0.2100 WHEN 2 THEN       0.0600 WHEN 4 THEN       0.2100  ELSE 0 END)+((e.min_price-(e.min_price/(1+(CASE e.tax_class_id WHEN 1 THEN       0.2100 WHEN 2 THEN       0.0600 WHEN 4 THEN       0.2100  ELSE 0 END))*CASE e.tax_class_id WHEN 1 THEN       0.2100 WHEN 2 THEN       0.0600 WHEN 4 THEN       0.2100  ELSE 0 END))*CASE e.tax_class_id WHEN 1 THEN       0.2100 WHEN 2 THEN       0.0600 WHEN 4 THEN       0.2100  ELSE 0 END) ) AS m_max_price FROM `catalog_product_index_price` AS `e`


    INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=5 AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id = '49'
    LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `cisi` ON (cisi.product_id=e.entity_id) AND (cisi.website_id = '1') WHERE (e.status = 1) AND ( e.website_id = '1' ) AND ( e.customer_group_id = 0) AND (e.min_price -(e.min_price/(1+(CASE e.tax_class_id WHEN 1 THEN       0.2100 WHEN 2 THEN       0.0600 WHEN 4 THEN       0.2100  ELSE 0 END))*CASE e.tax_class_id WHEN 1 THEN       0.2100 WHEN 2 THEN       0.0600 WHEN 4 THEN       0.2100  ELSE 0 END)+((e.min_price-(e.min_price/(1+(CASE e.tax_class_id WHEN 1 THEN       0.2100 WHEN 2 THEN       0.0600 WHEN 4 THEN       0.2100  ELSE 0 END))*CASE e.tax_class_id WHEN 1 THEN       0.2100 WHEN 2 THEN       0.0600 WHEN 4 THEN       0.2100  ELSE 0 END))*CASE e.tax_class_id WHEN 1 THEN       0.2100 WHEN 2 THEN       0.0600 WHEN 4 THEN       0.2100  ELSE 0 END)  IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY `m_max_price` DESC
```

Comment: Did you try disabling all custom modules ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help other, this issue are the MANAdev modules, they need to be upgraded for the upgrade to work en when you enable flat catalog.